# Python - Correlation: Error unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'generator' and 'int'

Tags: python, scipy, correlation, recommendation-engine

I am trying to execute a python code and I am getting an error

```
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'generator' and 'int'
```

**Code :**

```
def getCorrelation(user1,user2):
    ## user1 and user2 are two series
    list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,78,9,12]
    user1=np.array(user1[i] for i in list1)

    user2=np.array(user2[i] for i in list1)


    return correlation(user1,user2)

getCorrelation(user1,user2)
```

Comment: There's not a `/` in your code, so the error is coming from something you haven't shown us.

Comment: Even tho the code is missing, my guess would be that you need to add(at least) ".next()" after your generator to get the operation to work.

Comment: The full traceback message (select and use CTRL/K to format as code) would be helpful in isolating this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `user` expressions produce arrays containing a generator:

```
In [108]: np.array(i for i in alist)                                                 
Out[108]: array(<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f0b7bc98e60>, dtype=object)
```

With a proper list comprehension:

```
In [109]: np.array([i for i in alist])                                               
Out[109]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

The traceback should show that the error occurs when such an array is passed to the `correlation` function.

```
In [110]: np.array(i for i in alist)/2                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-110-a87b95ad6f4b> in <module>
----> 1 np.array(i for i in alist)/2

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'generator' and 'int'
```

Or testing a simple generator:

```
In [111]: g = (i for i in alist)                                                     
In [113]: g                                                                          
Out[113]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f0b7bc9b0f8>
In [114]: g/2                                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-f5357a50c56f> in <module>
----> 1 g/2

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'generator' and 'int'
```

Answer (score -1):

give a look in the user1, user2 type this can tell you some thing.
use: type(user1) and type(user2) and see the output.